# CSS Stylesheet Formatting Help

Tags: css

Can somebody look at my stylesheets and tell me how I can get the second row menu where it says login, register, remove ads to be centered on that second row? I can't figure it out

Here is my stylesheet: http://pastebin.com/dCkgJK54

Here is where the menu is implemented: http://pastebin.com/Nvrz4RZf

Thanks a lot.. it is in a wordpress theme.

Here is the site needing it if it's helpful: http://artistpromotion.net78.net/

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same `id` - they're supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the second menu's UL#tpmn needs these rules applied to it:

```
margin:0 auto;
position:static;
overflow:hidden;
display:block;
```

Also, for good measure, you should also apply `text-align:center` to its containing element.

Also, it appears that there are more than one UL with the same id (#tpmn). You should give one of them a different ID to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can center static elements using auto margins. From the W3C:

> If both 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' are 'auto', their used values
>   are equal. This horizontally centers the element with respect to the
>   edges of the containing block.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth

Applied to your site:

```
#tpmn {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that should be easy, however your page is formatted with quite a few css errors. Right away I noticed that there are several list items that all have the same id of "cts". These should be given classes as id's need to be unique. Try running your file through the w3c css validator: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Once your page is formatted correctly, you can use text-align center on the parent container, or if you have to position them absolutely as they are now, then give the parent container a width, position it left 50% and give it a negative margin-left of half the width. If your still having trouble, put it in a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) and it will be much easier to help you out.